# Voltage line switcher?

Tags: voltage, relay, power-electronics

If I have two voltage lines, say 5V and 12V, and I want to switch between using these two, is there such a device that can be controlled to connect one line, then connect the other?

I was thinking of using some relays that I have, but realized that would require two relays, one for each line. I could just turn the relays on and off separately. But is there a single device that can do the same thing? Like I could connect both 5V and 10V to two inputs, and also have two outputs, still at 5V and 12V, but have a control capability to switch between output use.

Comment: I think the 10V should be 12V?

Answer (score 2):

If I do understand your question correctly, I think you can just use one relay, but "the other way around" (instead of 1 output serving 2 outputs, using it as 2 inputs serving 1 output):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f99g3h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>